# I'm scared if my school can see what I'm searching

Tags: domain-admin

So I accidently clicked some sketchy website called "doxbin.org" and in that website clicked a dox called "rapey org owner" and I realised I can't deletet search history because of my school administrators so I'm sooo paranoid do they see that I'm also on a school provided device so I am 99 percent sure they can see that if they can how do they see it do they check it themselves or do they get a alert of some kind

Comment: If it is "their" device then they can see everything you do if they want to.  Deleting your search history wouldn't help.  However, we can't tell you whether or not they get alerts, periodically check, or don't bother with any kind of checking.  As a general rule of thumb though If you don't want them to see what you are doing, then don't use their device.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone makes mistakes.
You accidentally clicked on a website. That cannot be helped.
How they could, or would do it is up to them, some maybe just ignoring it (I don't know) some others maybe very strictly and carefully looking trough everything. But I don't think you are in any danger, just because of a accidental click on a URL.

It would be totally different if you **browsed that website(continued to browse it, still - realizing it might be against the rules of your school, and tried to hide that fact**